# Configurator pattern design issues

Tags: design-patterns, configuration

I'm struggling with a nice design for managing configuration loaded from a file and its propagation to all configurable objects. The application in question is in Kotlin/Java, but this question equally applies to pretty much any OO language. At this moment, I have the following design.

1. There is the immutable `Config` class that simply stores all configuration data.
2. There are major classes representing various components of the application. Let's say one of them is called `Server`. These clases know nothing of `Config`, and they shouldn't anyway for a variety of reasons: separation of concerns (why should `Server` care whether its parameters come from a config file or set by a unit test?), decoupling (`Config` contains a lot of parameters that have nothing to do with `Server`) and avoiding pervasive dependencies.
3. There is a `Configurator` class for every major class representing a configurable component of the application. For example, there's the `ServerConfigurator` class. The job of a configurator is to apply config settings to a particular component. So `ServerConfigurator` knows what parameters to take from a `Config` and how to apply them to a `Server`. So it's a variety of the Mediator pattern. It's a responsibility of a component to ask a configurator to apply the configuration (usually in the form of a `configurator.configure(this)` call). This ensures that configuration doesn't change unexpectedly—it only happens when a component asks for it. For example, `Sever` may have a loop in which it re-applies the configuration once in a while, in case it has been changed.
4. There's an application-wide service that loads the configuration (from an XML file in my case, but that can be easily changed), packs it into a `Config`, and supplies it into various configurators (in the form of a `configuration.setConfig(newConfig)` call). Then the new configuration may be picked up by various components through the appropriate configurators whenever they feel like it.

All this works and looks nice enough for my purpose, except one little thing: since configurators must be able to apply configuration parameters to respective components, the configurable properties of those components can't be `private`. In C++, I'd simply make configurators friends of the respective components, but in Java, I need to make the properties at least package-private or even `public`. Which is, of course, no fun, because now anyone can just change those properties, which can be surprising and unsafe, especially for multi-threaded components. It's one thing when a component explicitly tells a configurator to configure it—it happens in the right thread. But when someone just randomly change a property from the outside—ouch! That can't be good. It's not *that* much of a problem in my case since the components are pretty much isolated by design, but it still feels... inelegant.

Is there a reasonable way to implement this pattern in a more encapsulating manner? I was thinking along the lines of wrapping the configurable properties in some wrappers and then passing them to the configurator from *inside* the configurable component, but that seems tedious and ugly: I really want components to be as independent as possible.

Another way would be to make those properties private, but expose them through an abstract interface, which would be implemented by an inner class. So I'd have a `ServerConfigurable` interface declaring the configurable `Server` properties, and then I'd implement it in the `Server.MyConfigurable` class, which would just delegate to the appropriate `Server` properties. And then `Server` would call `configurator.configure(myConfigurable)` (where `myConfigurable` is an instance of `Server.MyConfigurable`) instead of `configurator.configure(this)`. I think this approach could actually work... but requires additional boilerplate code, which isn't nice either.

Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect, but here's the `Configurable` approach, as I couldn't think of anything better.

First, here's an example of a trivial `Config` class in Kotlin.

```kotlin
data class Config(val serverPort: Int)
// We also need some function to actually get a Config instance from somewhere...
```

Here's the polymorphic interface for `Configurator`.

```kotlin
interface Configurator<T> {
    fun configure(configurable: T)
}
```

And here's an example of a component that uses a configurator. In a real application, there would be several such components, each providing its own `Configurable` interface.

```kotlin
class Server(private val configurator: Configurator<ServerConfigurable>) {
    private val configurable = Configurable()
    private var serverPort: Int = defaultServerPort()

    fun run() {
        configurator.configure(configurable)
        // listen at port serverPort, it is now configured
        System.err.println("serverPort = $serverPort")
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun defaultServerPort() = 1234
    }

    private inner class Configurable : ServerConfigurable {
        override fun setServerPort(port: Int) {
            this@Server.serverPort = port
        }
    }
}

interface ServerConfigurable {
    // Kotlin doesn't support write-only properties, so we use setters
    fun setServerPort(port: Int)
}
```

Note that everything `Server` knows about `Configurator<ServerConfigurable>` is that it is able to `configure()` anything implementing `ServerConfigurable`. It doesn't know where that configuration comes from, how it is loaded, what other parameters it contains, etc. On the other hand, all `Configurator` knows about `ServerConfigurable` is that it needs a `port` of type `Int`. It doesn't know how and when it is used (if at all).

It is `Server`'s responsibility to invoke `configure()` when it thinks it's the right time to update configuration.

Here's an example of an abstract class used to implement actual configurators.

```kotlin
abstract class AbstractConfigurator<C, T>(initialConfig: C) : Configurator<T> {
    var config: C // we don't want to expose @Volatile as an implementation detail
        get() = currentConfig
        set(value) {
            currentConfig = value
        }
    @Volatile private var currentConfig = initialConfig

    override fun configure(configurable: T) {
        // Template Method pattern: the actual configuration happens in apply(),
        // here we may want to check that the config hasn't changed, for example.
        val configSnapshot = currentConfig
        apply(configSnapshot, configurable)
    }

    abstract fun apply(config: C, configurable: T)
}
```

Whatever service is responsible for actually loading and applying configuration, all it needs to do is to set `config` to the new value. It will then be picked up by a `configure()` call.

Here's an actual implementation of a configurator. Again, there would be several such implementations in a real application.

```kotlin
class ServerConfigurator(initialConfig: Config)
    : AbstractConfigurator<Config, ServerConfigurable>(initialConfig) {

    override fun apply(config: Config, configurable: ServerConfigurable) {
        configurable.setServerPort(config.serverPort)
    }
}
```

And here's a (silly) test that demonstrates that the whole thing at least compiles and more or less works:

```java
        ServerConfigurator configurator = new ServerConfigurator(new Config(1111));
        Server server = new Server(configurator);
        server.run(); // should print 1111
        configurator.setConfig(new Config(2222));
        server.run(); // should print 2222
```

**Dependencies and encapsulation**

As far as dependencies go, it mostly satisfies my design requirements. `Server` knows absolutely nothing about configuration implementation details. All it knows about the configuration environment is:

1. The `configure()` method, which is absolutely necessary if I want `Server` to be in control of when the configuration is applied.
2. The need to expose some `Configurable` interface. This is only necessary if I want to keep configurable properties `private`, which I do.

On the other hand, the configurator implementation knows nothing about `Server` except that it somehow provides a `ServerConfigurable` interface implementation, which exposes just enough functionality to pass the appropriate configuration parameters to `Server`.

What's especially nice is that `Server.Configurable` is 100% private and can never be accessed in any way except that through the `configure()` method. This completely eliminates any risk of accidentally assigning to configurable properties.

**Pros and cons**

Pros:

1. Easy to implement if the `apply()` method implementation is fast enough *or* `configure()` isn't called very often.
2. Separation of concerns. Configurable components and configurators know just enough about each other to be able to do their job. This could be improved further by removing the `Configurator` interface altogether, replacing it with something like `Consumer<ServerConfigurable>`. This way `Server` will have absolutely *no* dependencies on the configuration framework. The disadvantage is that Kotlin/Java interop is somewhat clumsy when it comes to void-returning method references or lambdas, like `Consumer`.
3. The ability to change configuration on-the-fly.
4. The clients control exactly when the configuration is updated. Easy to guarantee thread-safety this way. All we need to keep in mind that whenever we call `configure()`, it may call `Configurable` methods and therefore change configurable properties.

Cons:

1. Boilerplate. It's a thread-off between `private` properties and simplicity. There would be no need for `ServerConfigurable` if `serverPort` was public, which was exactly the reason why I asked this question in the first place...
2. If the `apply()` method implementation is slow enough, and `configure()` is called often enough, we may want to modify `configure()` to check whether the config has been changed since the last `apply()` call. This, however, complicates things quite a lot. For example, in my case `Server` may need to create `ClientConnection` instances to handle different client connections. They are an implementation detail of `Server` and therefore don't have their own `ClientConnectionConfigurable` interface, reusing `ServerConfigurable` instead. However, as soon as we try to use the same configurator for different objects, it becomes harder to implement saving of the last applied configuration. We'd need a whole hashtable of them, and some way to clean up unused entries (for example, disconnected clients). If we decide to go with different configurator instances for every object instead, then we'll have to somehow propagate configuration changes every time. Thankfully, this is mostly a non-issue in most languages, since sharing immutable data is as simple as passing lightweight references or primitive values around, and therefore real `apply()` implementations should work very fast in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not claiming my approach is better than yours, but it is different, and the difference might provide you with some food for thought. Comments follow after the pseudocode:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
    _x = "default value";
    _y = 42;
    _z = new Z();
  }
  Foo(Configuration cfg, string scope) {
    _z = new Z();
    initFromConfiguration(cfg, scope);
  }
  void initFromConfiguration(Configuration cfg, string scope) {
    // I am using a leading underscore to denote an instance variable
    _x = cfg.lookupString(scope + ".x");
    _y = cfg.lookupInt(scope + ".y");
    _z.initFromConfiguration(cfg, scope + ".z"); // initialize a nested object
  }
};
class Bar { ... } // similar design pattern to class Foo
class Server
{
  Server() {
    _foo = new Foo();
    _bar = new Bar();
  }
  Server(Configuration cfg, string scope) {
    _foo = new Foo();
    _bar = new Bar();
    initFromConfig(cfg, scope);
  }
  void initFromConfig(Configuration cfg, string scope) {
    _foo.initFromConfig(cfg, scope + ".foo");
    _bar.initFromConfig(cfg, scope + ".bar");
  }
}

main() {
  appConfig = ...; // probably parse a config file
  Server s = new Server();
  s.initFromConfig(appConfig, "app1");
  ... // run the application  
}
```

Notes:

1. Rather than have a `Configurator` class acting as a mediator between an object and its configuration, I just have each class initialise itself directly from a `Configuration` object. This approach reduces boilerplate code.
2. The `Configuration` class provides type-safe lookup operations: `lookupString()`, `lookupInt()`, `lookupBoolean()` and so on.
3. The lookup operations retrieve values based on a hierarchical name, such as `app1.foo.x`.
4. The `initfromConfiguration()` operation in class `Foo` shows that an object can initialize simple instance variables directly by calling a lookup operation, and initialize a nested object by calling `initfromConfiguration()` on the nested object.
5. Some people may suggest that `initFromConfiguration()` should be deleted and its functionality put into the constructor of a class. However, doing that would *require* an object to be initialized from a `Configuration` object. Keeping `initFromConfiguration()` separate permits objects to be initialized in an alternative way, for example, by calling setter operations. But there is no harm in providing several constructors, one of which calls `initFromConfiguration()`.

Comment: This is a common configuration pattern, but I don't like it for its pervasive dependency. References to `Configuration` flood the entire codebase. It's OK for code that's already very tightly coupled (either by design or because it's legacy code *lacking* design), but when I see it in a class that's more or less independent and can be reused somewhere else, I don't want to bring the entire configuration with me. Another thing I don't like is that property names represented with strings (`".x"`, `".y"`).

Comment: @SergeiTachenov I agree that it couples each class to a `Configuration`. But the approach you suggested couples each class to `Configurator`, so coupling happens either way. One way to avoid such coupling is to use dependency injection, like in the Spring Framework.

Comment: `Configurator` is just one method that says nothing at all about where the configuration comes from, what it contains, how it is represented, etc. It's an example of Dependency Inversion. In this sense, `Configurator` is a part of the client, and the rest of the configuration environment depends on `Configurator`, not the other way around. For example, there is no way `Server` accidentally retrieves a wrong parameter from the configuration registry. And how does injection helps to avoid coupling?

Comment: Speaking of which... Perhaps it's a design error to have the `Configurator` interface at all! I could easily declare the `Server`'s constructor parameter as `(ServerConfigurable) -> Unit` (or `Consumer<ServerConfigurable>` in Java), thereby avoiding *any* kind of dependency on the configuration framework. Then I'd just pass `configurator::configure` to the constructor.

Comment: @sergei-tachenov What I suggested did not specify how the `Configuration` object is populated. `Configuration` could be an `interface` rather than a concrete `class`, so I don't see how it results in *more* coupling that your `Configurator` API. The Spring Framework reads an XML config file and uses reflection to create objects and set properties on them (including references between objects). Thus, the "coupling" between objects and their config is not hardcoded into the application, but rather comes from the XML config file.

Comment: Still, dependency injection or not, the component has access to *all* configuration. A lazy developer can easily query a configuration parameter that `Server` shouldn't care about, without giving a second thought. Then, at some point, when `Server` is moved into another module that doesn't have that parameter at all, things suddenly break. In my case, it's impossible to do without changing the `ServerConfigurable` interface.